# object lost when submitting a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my MVC-app there's a part where a user will have to review an item before send it. He has to choose how many of them he would like to send.

Here's the view as I wrote it down:

```
 @model MyApp.Models.ObjInfo

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Dispatch Item";
    }

    <h2>Dispatch Item</h2>
    <h3>
        <label>
            For: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.m_OtherObj.m_Name)
        </label>
    </h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>OBJ_INFO</legend>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Obj Number <br/>
                            Obj Color <br/>
                            Mana Cost <br/>
                            (...)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.m_OtherObj.m_Name)<br/>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.m_OtherObj.m_Color)<br/>
(...)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p>
                    <span style="font-size: 1.2em">
                        Number In Stock: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.m_NbStock)<br/>
                        Number already reserved (Ebay Auctions): @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.m_QtyAlreadyReserved)<br/>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Number items to dispatch: <input type="number" min="0" max="99" name="numberSent" value="int" step="0"/>
                </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </fieldset>
    }
    <span style="color:red; font-size: 1.7em; font-style: italic;">@ViewData["ErrorMessage"]</span>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to listing", "SearchIndex")
        </p>
    }
```

Well, you get the idea. The thing is, everytime I load the app, make my way to this page, then click on the "Save" button, the item is NULL even though the signature of my method is ok:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DispatchItem(ObjInfo itemToSend, int? numberSent)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      if (numberSent == null)
      {
         ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "Please put a value in the 'Number items to dispatch' field. Thank you.";
         return View(itemToSend);
      }

      if (numberSent > itemToSend.m_NbStock)
      {
         ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = m_TooManyItems;
         return View(itemToSend);
      }
   }
   return RedirectToAction("SearchIndex");
 }
```

So, as I mentioned, every time I get on the first line, the object is null. But the first time the page load, the object load as well and the correct information displays.

Can anybody help me out? Thank you!

Comment: Did you intend to set `numberSent` to be a `nullable` type?

Comment: Nope, but since it may be because of the "input" field, I had to avoid this case.
Rather new in using cshtml and Html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form doesn't actually have any values to post back to the server.  You include some of these:

```
@Html.DisplayFor()
```

But those don't create form elements.  They just output the value for display.  You should probably also include some of these for your model properties:

```
@Html.HiddenFor()
```

(Make sure they're inside the `form` tag.)

This would create some `input` elements in the rendered HTML to be included in the POST back to the action method.  Otherwise, without any `input` elements, the HTML `form` is empty and has nothing to POST to the server.

Comment: How come my other forms work without hidden fields then? is it because I'm using css classes "label-field" and "editor-field"?

Comment: @HerveS: What `@Html` helpers do you use on those other forms?  The CSS classes have nothing to do with it, they're just for styling.  But if you use something like `@Html.EditorFor` or `@Html.TextBoxFor` then those render actual HTML `input` elements.  Take a look at the rendered HTML in your browser's debugging tools to see the difference.  Watch the requests/responses in something like FireBug to see the form elements constructed into the POST.  Regardless of server-side code or CSS styling, the HTML `form` needs data-containing HTML elements.

Comment: I am using mostly Html.EditorFor and Html.TextBoxFor, you are right on this.
Ok, I think I get what you mean. Basically, I just "display" information about the object I sent out, but I never "kept" this object anyway and I need to do so in order to be able to send it back to the POST. Right?

Comment: @HerveS: Correct.  The actual rendered HTML is disconnected from the server-side objects.  So the entire state of those objects needs to be stored in client-side HTML form between the rendering of the page and the post back to the server.  This is most often done by populating `input` elements (text box, check box, select, hidden, etc.) with the components of that data.  Then, when all of those individual pieces of data are posted back to the server, the server-side model binding does it best to try to figure out what complex object they represent.